# CRM OnPrem--> Plugin--> Connect to External (SOAP) Webservice Error with connection

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics

I am trying to connect from CRM Plugin to External SOAP API. It gives me error.

I am using Isolation Mode as None. 
When I connect the same API using Console APP it works fine. I executed the Console APP from Server and it connects and responds Fine.

I googled a bit got some leads but probably I lack capability to understand/ pinpoint the issue.

**Code Snippet below**

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("URL");                  

                    request.Method = "GET";

                    //request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("USERNAME", "PASSWORD");

                    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

                    HttpWebResponse webresponse = (HttpWebResponse)response;
                    if (webresponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    {
                        tracing.Trace($" Resposne is correct i.e OK");

                    }
```

When I debug using Plugin Registration Tool, Tool breaks up and exits.

---

**Error from Tracing:**

```
 A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond


    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)

       at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket&amp; socket, IPAddress&amp; address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception&amp; exception)
       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
       at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
```

Comment: Does your console app run on the same machine as the plugin? If not, maybe your server is somehow blocked from accessing the remotes service. Can you access other URLs from the plugin? Can you access a URL on localhost? Just output the raw response to some test field in the entity or write it out to your log.

Comment: Try to change isolation to sandbox

Comment: @Atzmon Just to be clear if I understand your statement, I ran the console app from my Local machine and also from server where CRM is hosted. 
I ran my plugin code for CRM as in Isolation Mode.
One more thing I tried to call Public SOAP API (from plugin) and even that threw Error.

Comment: @Sxntk I tried both None and Isolation and did not helped.

Comment: @AnkUser Are you able to change the design to use a Custom workflow activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Reason why it was not working:**

1. Customer (OnPrem) uses Proxy to connect to Web.
2. When I was running Console App on server it was running on my Logged on context (outside CRM) i.e. user who logged on Server.
3. However, When I tried to call website from CRM may it be from Isolation Mode = None OR Sandbox, The services that runs under specific user did not have proxy added to them.
4. For Example running plugin under Isolation Mode = NONE i.e. directly under the context of APPPool Service "crmtestappserv" did not have proxy and even using mere Internet Explored under the context of same user was not able to open google.com unless proxies were Added.

**Steps Taken to Solve the issue:** In our plugin Code, when we make an HTTP request we add proxy to the request. This solved our issue.